# Mina NIO networking - Packets not sending after initial startup

Tags: java, networking, client, server, mina

I currently have a problem while working with Mina. I am able to create a NIOAcceptor and Connector and connect the client to the server. Upon session being created in the Server, it sends the handshake packet which in turn validates and sends back validation to the server to see if files are up-to-date, etc. The server receives this validation and correctly deciphers the packet and sends the packet to the Client to display the game window. However, after this initial connection, I can no longer send packets to the server via the Client.

ServerHandler:

```
@Override
public void sessionOpened(IoSession session) {
    log.info("[Login] to [" + GameConstants.GAME_NAME + ": IoSession with {} opened", session.getRemoteAddress());
    Client c = new Client(session);
    connectedClients.add(session.getRemoteAddress().toString());
    session.setAttribute(Client.KEY, c);
    c.write(PacketCreator.getHandshake());
    // c.write(PacketCreator.getPing());
}

@Override
public void messageReceived(IoSession session, Object message) {
    PacketReader reader = new PacketReader((byte[]) message);
    Client c = (Client) session.getAttribute(Client.KEY);
    short header = reader.readShort();
    PacketHandler handler = PacketProcessor.getHandler(header);
    System.out.println("Received opcode: 0x" + Integer.toHexString(header).toUpperCase());
    if (handler != null) {
        handler.handlePacket(reader, c);
    } else {
        log.info("Received opcode: 0x" + Integer.toHexString(header).toUpperCase() + " with no handler.");
    }
}

@Override
public void exceptionCaught(IoSession session, Throwable cause) {
    System.out.println("session error");
}

@Override
public void sessionClosed(IoSession session) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Session closing: " + session.getRemoteAddress().toString());
    connectedClients.remove(session.getRemoteAddress().toString());
    Client c = (Client) session.getAttribute(Client.KEY);
    if (c != null) {
        c.disconnect();
        c.dispose();
    } else {
        log.warn("Client is null in sessionClosed for ip {} when it shouldn't be", session.getRemoteAddress());
    }
    super.sessionClosed(session);
}
```

ClientHandler:

```
@Override
public void sessionOpened(IoSession session) {
    System.out.println("Session opened: " + session);
    Server s = new Server(session);
    session.setAttribute(Server.KEY, s);
    s.write(PacketCreator.getPong());
}

@Override
public void messageReceived(IoSession session, Object message) {
    PacketReader reader = new PacketReader((byte[]) message);
    Server s = (Server) session.getAttribute(Server.KEY);
    short header = reader.readShort();
    PacketHandler handler = PacketProcessor.getHandler(header);
    if (handler != null) {
        handler.handlePacket(reader, s);
    } else {
        log.info("Received opcode: 0x" + Integer.toHexString(header).toUpperCase() + " with no handler.");
    }
}

@Override
public void exceptionCaught(IoSession session, Throwable cause) {
    System.out.println("session error");
    log.error("Exception caught in Server Handler: ", cause);
}

@Override
public void sessionClosed(IoSession session) throws Exception {
    // TODO
    System.out.println("session closed");
    super.sessionClosed(session);
}
```

Client (NIOConnection class):

```
public static void connectToServer() throws Throwable {
    NioSocketConnector connector = new NioSocketConnector();
    connector.setConnectTimeoutMillis(1000 * 30); // 30 seconds
    connector.getFilterChain().addLast("codec", new ProtocolCodecFilter(new ObjectSerializationCodecFactory()));
    connector.setHandler(new ClientHandler());
    IoSession session;
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (;;) {
        try {
            ConnectFuture future = connector.connect(new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 9494)); // 24.7.142.74
            future.awaitUninterruptibly();
            session = future.getSession();
            break;
        } catch (RuntimeIoException e) {
            log.error("Failed to connect", e);
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        }
    }
    session.getCloseFuture().awaitUninterruptibly();
}
```

Server (NIOAcceptor class):

```
private static void initializeLoginServer() {
    PacketProcessor.registerHandlers();
    acceptor = new NioSocketAcceptor();
    // acceptor.getFilterChain().addLast("codec", new ProtocolCodecFilter(new TextLineCodecFactory(Charset.forName("UTF-8"))));// TODO: encoding/decoding packets
    acceptor.getFilterChain().addLast("codec", new ProtocolCodecFilter(new ObjectSerializationCodecFactory()));
    acceptor.getSessionConfig().setReadBufferSize(2048);
    acceptor.getSessionConfig().setIdleTime(IdleStatus.BOTH_IDLE, 10);
    acceptor.getSessionConfig().setTcpNoDelay(true);
    acceptor.setHandler(new ServerHandler(1));
    try {
        acceptor.bind(new InetSocketAddress(GameConstants.SERVER_PORT));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Could not bind. ", e);
    }
    log.info("Login Server: Listening on port " + GameConstants.SERVER_PORT);
}
```